# Why inserting a user object and making callout in a test throws CalloutException in Production?

Tags: callout, exception, failing-tests, insert, mixed-dml

I stumbled upon strange behavior when executing tests on deployment to production organization. In the test, I first insert a `User` object, some other objects and then as the last one, a `CampaignMember` object. Inserting `CampaignMember` triggers after insert event, which makes a callout to external service through queueable class.

When I do not create a user, everything works fine. I can create as many objects as I want and then insert `CampaignMember`, and callout is made fine. However, if I try to insert `User` object as well, I get a `CalloutException`:

```
    System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

This only happens on deployment to production. If I try to deploy to any sandbox running all tests on deployment, I don't get the exception, whole deployment works fine, test works fine, `User`, `CampaignMember` and all the other objects are created fine and callout is made.

I know there can be a problem inserting `User` and other objects in the same transaction causing Mixed DML exceptions, which I suspected could have something to do with this problem, but the callout is done in a separate transaction than `User` insert. It is made in a queuable class, which is executed after `Test.stopTest()`, and it does not collide with insert of any other objects in this or other tests.

Why does this happen with `User` insert and happens only in the Production execution of the test?

My test code:

```
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new SubscribeCampaignMemberMock());

    Campaign campaign = UnitTestFactory.createCampaign('Test Campaign');
    insert campaign;

    Account account = UnitTestFactory.createAccount('Test Account');
    insert account;

    Contact contact1 = UnitTestFactory.createContact('Test Contact 1',
          'testcontact1@testcontact.test', account.Id);
    Contact contact2 = UnitTestFactory.createContact('Test Contact 2', 
          'testcontact2@testcontact.test', account.Id);

    insert contact1;
    insert contact2;

    User user = UnitTestFactory.createUser('testuser@testuser.test');

    // If I remove this insert, test will work 
    insert user;

        CampaignMember campaignMember1 = 
             UnitTestFactory.createCampaignMember(campaign, contact1);
        CampaignMember campaignMember2 = 
             UnitTestFactory.createCampaignMember(campaign, contact2);

    // This insert triggers creation of queueable
    insert new CampaignMember[]{campaignMember1, campaignMember2};

    Test.startTest();
    System.enqueueJob(new ActivateCampaignMember(new Campaign[] {campaign}));

    // This call to Test.stopTest() executes queueable, callout is 
    // executed and exception is thrown
    Test.stopTest();

    // Assert
    ...
```

Please don't mind the `UnitTestFactory` methods, they just return new instances of objects with mandatory fields populated.

EDIT 1:

I also tried to encapsulate the user creation to a `System.runAs()` block, but it did not solve the issue. 
Sandboxes I tried deployment on were Developer and Partial Copy freshly refreshed from Production.

EDIT 2:

I tried wrapping

```
    Test.startTest();
    System.enqueueJob(new ActivateCampaignMember(new Campaign[] {campaign}));
    Test.stopTest();
```

in a `System.runAs()` block and the exception is still thrown.

EDIT 3:

I tried moving the User creation logic to `@TestSetup`. 
All 13 tests in the test class started getting CalloutException on deployment to Production, but again, they all passed on deployment to Partial Copy sandbox.

EDIT 4:

I compared the logs from test run in Partial Copy sandbox and Production, nothing except timestamps and Ids of jobs and objects is different on log level granularity levels of Database - Finest, Callouts - Info, Apex Code - Debug. The difference is only in the end of log, where Prod throws exception:

Partial copy sandbox log:

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p58000009Emts|ActivateCampaignMemberTest.membersWithExistingEditorsAreSkipped
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p5E000000KSFJ|SubscribeCampaignMember
USER_DEBUG|[34]|DEBUG|Executing Campaign Member subscription callout with queueable job id 7075E00000NYiHsQAL
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SubscribeCampaignMember
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p58000009Emtr|ActivateCampaignMember
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ActivateCampaignMember    
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ActivateCampaignMemberTest.membersWithExistingEditorsAreSkipped
```

Production log:

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p58000009Emts|ActivateCampaignMemberTest.membersWithExistingEditorsAreSkipped
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p58000009Ev2l|SubscribeCampaignMember
USER_DEBUG|[34]|INFO|Executing Campaign Member subscription callout with queueable job id 7075800004EUdslAAD
EXCEPTION_THROWN|[19]|System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
Class.HttpService.put: line 19, column 1
Class.SubscribeCampaignMember.execute: line 47, column 1
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SubscribeCampaignMember
FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
Class.HttpService.put: line 19, column 1
Class.SubscribeCampaignMember.execute: line 47, column 1
FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
Class.HttpService.put: line 19, column 1
Class.SubscribeCampaignMember.execute: line 47, column 1
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ActivateCampaignMemberTest.membersWithExistingEditorsAreSkipped
```

Comment: I have moved the extended debugging conversation [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73589/discussion-on-question-by-andrej-lucansky-why-inserting-a-user-object-and-making).

Comment: What's the use of moving these discussions to chat when it gets deleted before anyone goes back to update the thread with whatever solved it???